# How can I get reliable / consistent maximum memory usage results under dot net

Tags: c#, .net, memory, performance-testing

We have various tests that monitor our application's (or sub components) memory usage under various scenarios, to check for regressions. The problem is that our measurements (using `Process.Refresh(); Process.PrivateMemorySize64`) fluctuate wildly over different runs.

What we are currently doing is polling via a background thread every `X` milliseconds. We compare the max value reached to a benchmark, and pass/fail accordingly.

Interestingly, reducing the time between polls significantly reduces the maximum memory value recorded. In one example, reading the memory every 100ms gives a maximum of 360MB, every 10ms gives 147MB, and every 1ms gives 35ms.
Presumably the increased number of observations somehow makes GC behaviour more aggressive.

I suppose that the main problem is that what we are trying to measure, "maximum memory usage", is not particularly well defined. 
If there's plenty of memory available, the GC might not bother to kick in, so memory usage will appear higher.

Is there a standard way to measure memory usage under dot net to guard against performance degradation?

Answer (score 1):

> I suppose that the main problem is that what we are trying to measure, "maximum memory usage", is not particularly well defined. If there's plenty of memory available, the GC might not bother to kick in, so memory usage will appear higher.

This is your problem. It's not arbitrary that a garbage-collected runtime would use more memory when it's available. These algorithms perform *substantially* better when they have a larger memory space to "play around in". For an objective analysis, you *must* use a tool to analyze only the reachable set, which is not affected by garbage collected behavior.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for such a tool? At the moment, my best ideas are: call `GC.Collect()` frequently, or somehow limit the process' allowed memory.

Comment: When I'm working in Java, I use YourKit Java Profiler (with VisualVM as a free but slower alternative) for this. I haven't used specific tools for .NET enough to make a recommendation. Regarding `GC.Collect()`: without tools your results won't be accurate enough to make any sort of conclusion about anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PerformanceCounter  class` to measure your memomry usage

link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.aspx

manualy you can use `Memory Profiler tool` to inspect your memory

link : http://memprofiler.com/